# Dynamic chart using Html and Javascript in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I want to create an html and javascript pie chart in my asp.net web application. 
Can I do this by coding in my code behind?
I want to draw the chart from my code behind as html. I use .InnerHtml property for this.

Comment: You should use a chart control... there are free ones like http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14422. Why would you want to do that in html ?

Comment: I don't want to use any any asp.net controls for chart

Comment: Well, Ajax.net has a dojo integration (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/Dojo-AjaxDotNet.aspx). And dojo has charts (http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2010/07/13/dive-into-dojo-charting/). I don't know if this part of dojo is integrated in ajax.net though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Google Visualisation Charts, see [ASP.Net forum post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1539888/3750698.aspx) regarding this.

Another javascript/jQuery chart is FLot see [google code](http://code.google.com/p/flot/wiki/FlotUsage) and this **[link](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/)** for examples

See [codeplex page](http://gvapi4aspnet.codeplex.com/) for google visualisation api control for asp.net

An iteractive chart using Flash is [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a [chart](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2008/11/12/microsoft-chart-controls-for-the-net-framework.aspx) control you can use.

Answer (score 0):

[High Charts](http://www.highcharts.com/) is a javascript charting library that's free to use for non-commercial purposes.  Its much more interactive than the Microsoft image-based charting controls.